# MVC3,PartialViews,Ajax Passing values

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

This is the model `example.cs`

```
namespace View_Partial_Editor.Models
{
    public class ExampleView
    {
            ...
            public string Field1 { get; set; }
            public string Field2 { get; set; }           
            public string Field3 { get; set; }
            public string Field4 { get; set; }
            public string Field5 { get; set; }
            ...

    }
}
```

I have this view  `example.cshtml`:

```
@model View_Partial_Editor.Models.ExampleView

@{Html.RenderPartial("EditExample",Model);}    

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field1)
```

Then i have this partialView `EditExample.cshtml`:

```
@model View_Partial_Editor.Models.ExampleView    

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field1)        

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditExample", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "partial" }))
{
   <div>
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m, "Editor", null)
   </div>

   <p>
      <input  id="buttona" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
   </p>        
}
```

I have this controller `ExampleController`:

```
namespace View_Partial_Editor.Controllers
{
    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Example/    
        public ActionResult Example()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditExample(ExampleView example)
        {
            example.Field1 ="7";

            return View("Example", example);
        }    
    }
}
```

And this is the editor that is called in the partial `editor.cshtml`

```
@model View_Partial_Editor.Models.ExampleView

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field1 )
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Field1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field1)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field2)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Field2)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field2)
</div>
```

My problem is that i want to modify the data of the model in the controller in the ajax call, and return the model modified to the `exampleView`.But when the ajax called finish the value that i change in the controller is not changed in the model

Edit: The thing that i want is to send the call to the ajax methos, save something in the database, then modify the model, and in the example view i want to have that model with the changes.

In this moment, if i replace the partial view with the result of the ajax, the model in the example view is not modified.Another way is to replace the full example view, so the model is received there, but i have to pass a lot of fields using Html.HiddenFor, is possible to make this without replacing the views only returnng the model with the changes

Comment: Please show code for controller in ajax call

Comment: The code for the ajax call is there is the EditExample function


the idea is that the example model, in the exampleview after the call, has the value of the field1 ahnge to seven, but has the old value still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `ModelState.Clear()` in your HttpPost action method.  Html helpers use the values in the ModelState first, then the Model.  If you change a value in the model on a post therefore, you need to clear the value from the ModelState.

Comment: Without using ajax this solves the problem, but i have to make the call with ajax, so it;s not solving the problem thx anyway